# Msbuild add reference path

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I am using TeamCity to build my solutions remotely and one of my projects has a reference path which is different from the build server. Is there anyway that I can change or add the reference hintpath in the command line of the Visual Studio Runner before the project builds so that the dependency is resolved?

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="FeedOSAPI_vc10, Version=2.5.2.1, Culture=neutral>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>path</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="FeedOS_Managed_vc10, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>"path</HintPath>
</Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can accomplish this is to use environment variables, both on `Build Servers` and `developer workstations`. You can create a binary repository, it can be VCS repository or simlpe file server, and after that you can have one source code for projects which will be able to build anywhere, where the prerequisite conditions are met.

1. [Create environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), for example **BinRepo**, both on Build Server and on dev machine.
2. Use it in the project like this:

   ```
   <Reference Include="FeedOSAPI_vc10, Version=2.5.2.1, Culture=neutral>
       <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
       <HintPath>$(BinRepo)FeedOS\FeedOSAPI_vc10.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="FeedOS_Managed_vc10, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral>
       <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
       <HintPath>$(BinRepo)FeedOS\FeedOS_Managed_vc10.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   ```

Thus you have single code base, and you do not need to specify it elsewhere in the project or from the command line (but you have the ability to do so).

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to use the environment variable in the project -> properties -> reference paths GUI?

Comment: You can use environment variables as ordinary variables of msbuild: **$(VarName)** - that's it.